# how find user that rename table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

in share database
one user rename table
now i want user id that this work

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @newtablename sysname = 'newtablename';
create table dbo.atesttable(id int);
exec sp_rename 'dbo.atesttable', @newtablename;


select 
    suser_sname([Transaction SID]) as thelogin,
    (select name from sys.database_principals where sid = [Transaction SID]) as thedbuser,
    [Begin Time], [End Time],
    cast([rowlog contents 0] as nvarchar(max)), 
    cast([rowlog contents 1] as nvarchar(max))
from sys.fn_dblog(null, null)
where [Transaction ID] in
(
    select [Transaction ID]
    from sys.fn_dblog(null, null)
    where [Lock Information] like '%' + cast(object_id(@newtablename) as varchar(50)) + '%'
    intersect
    select [Transaction ID]
    from sys.fn_dblog(null, null)
    where convert(nvarchar(max), [rowlog contents 0]+[rowlog contents 1]+[rowlog contents 2]+[rowlog contents 3]+[rowlog contents 4], 2)
    like '%' + convert(nvarchar(max), cast(@newtablename as varbinary(200)), 2) + '%'
    --where cast([rowlog contents 1] as nvarchar(max)) like '%' + left(@newtablename, 10) + '%'
);


exec ('drop table ' + @newtablename)
go
```